# Suitable chairs for hunched, digitigrade lizard people?

Tags: creature-design, anatomy, civilization, architecture

My humanoid lizardfolk are 6-7 foot tall digitigrades, some have a slightly hunched posture like Gollum/Smeagol. I'm wondering what kind of chairs that be suitable for these characteristics as well as their long tails? Obviously the chairs would need some gap at the back or the sides for the tail to slip through otherwise sitting would be uncomfortable.

Can you help me?

Comment: Are they hunched because of the weight distribution of their limbs and tail or are they actually hunched and unable to straighten their back?

Comment: I am always loving humanoids with tails but there is a lot about this already here.  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=chair+tail   Not voting to close because maybe the fact that these are hunched lizard people brings some nuance .

Comment: @JarredJones Yeah the distribution of their limbs and tails makes them slightly hunched.

Answer (score 8):

## What's your Tech level?

The kind of chairs you'll want depend on if these are primitive or sophisticated, modern or ancient. But here are my best targets:

1. **Pillows**: The humble pillow or floor pad is a simple, highly modular system allowing a wide variety of shapes and positions to be accommodated easily. Lay on it, prop your front up on it, stretch out a tail on one, lean forward and back. For thousands of years, humans have relied first and foremost on the modular pillow for resting, dining, entertaining (unless your lizard men eat all their non-reptilian guests...)

[image: pillows]  [image: lizard]

2. **Benches**: The fairly simple backless bench, combined with a table to lean over, will serve perfectly well, obstructing nothing.
   [image: bench]
3. **Massage chairs:** For your more modern and civilized reptoids, I'd go with something to support all their parts while they recline in comfort. The best human equivalent is a massage chair, where people sit reclined forward while the rear of the seat is completely open. Low-tech versions of this can, of course, be made, and if they aren't made to fold and move like this one, the designs can be even simpler.

[image: chair]

4. **Sitting backwards**: With few adjustments, most armless chairs can be sat in backwards leaning forwards, an ideal position for your lizards.

[image: forward seat]

Comment: It's a medieval setting and they are very primitive, but they also occupy human villages and castles too.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this would probably work

[image]

where they would sit putting it between their leg, the same way a human would sit on a horse. The tail would freely accommodate on the read of the seat, and if they wanted they could lean forward, adopting the posture of an iguana standing on a rock.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Regular chairs

Or gamer chairs, if they are comfort creatures.

I am a programmer. I have many programmer friends and colleagues who hunch like smeagol, it's almost a job requirement. Some of them are over 6 ft tall.

Regular chairs seem to do for them, despite their constant nagging about back aches. I am almost sure they are human, so in their case it comes down to hunching like smeagol which is not natural for us. I swear to god I want to strap them sitting straight on their chairs just to get them to shut up. In the case of your lizardfolk, since its their natural stance, they should be fine.

Or...

## Bi chairs

Some years ago some guy complained on Twitter that his daughter wouldn't sit as a normal person. He made her a very uncanny chair so she could sit comfortably, as a practical dad joke. The internets, being what they are, dubbed the contraption a "bi chair - for people who can't sit straight<sup>TM</sup>".

Throughout the years new models have been designed by different companies, and now it's a thing of its own. Some models have a pad instead of a back support, which does facilitate hunching. Check the human in the top right corner of this image:

[image: A bi chair and nine ways to sit on it]

Source: https://mobile.twitter.com/cosetthetable/status/1309624334806286342

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go with this guy (shamelessly cribbed from Runescape via Google Images) as a template:

[image: Corrupted Lizardman]

I know, he's low-poly. It's not his fault, he was drawn that way. On the plus side he has the features we're after: digitgrade legs, reptilian (he's a lizardman, duh), hunched posture to account for the tail mass... he'll do. I'm going to call him Albert.

Now clearly Albert's kind would have some slightly different requirements for a seat than humans, elves and so on. There are a few obvious features that will make it basically impossible for them to ever have created chairs like we did:

- Tails don't mix with chair backs. Period. Oh, I know, some humans try to get inventive by putting tail slots or holes in the backs of their chairs, but we all know that's just not going to fly.
- Those feet do not sit flat, ever. They just don't bend that way.
- The skeleton isn't designed to sit upright, it is all arranged to lean forward.
- Differences in the pelvic structure mean that our lizardfolk are more comfortable sitting with their knees spread, kinda like a frat boy on a bus.

So let's start with the basics: stools. At some point in the development of seating every race goes from crouching to putting their butts on something - rocks, tree stumps, logs, whatever. Albert's people are no different here, but the articulation of the ankle and metatarso phalangeal joints as well as the structure of the pelvis means that they aren't comfortable just planting their feet in front of them. They're more likely to sit straddling a fallen tree with their hocks (those bits where the heels would be on a plantigrade walker) under their center of mass rather than sideways with feet forward.

Now the most comfortable stool for long-term sitting is one that lets your thighs be parallel to the ground with the feet - or toes in Albert's case - resting comfortably on the ground. In Albert's case that means a higher seat than humans with a similar hip height, because of the extra effective length of the lower leg. Sitting lower means folding the legs further back, but even at optimal height the hocks needs somewhere to go. Keep that in mind for later, it's quite important. And it's important that the thighs be parallel since the back of the thigh supports a portion of the weight. If it's not parallel then you get pressure points in the biceps femoris and it gets painful after a while. If you leave all the weight on the glutes you need lots of extra padding too.

So now that we've achieved stools, the next step is to add supports for the body to allow it to retain correct posture. For humans a fairly plain upright is all you need, since ideal seating posture mimics ideal standing posture from the waist up. For Albert, with that forward tilt to his torso, the best support would be a tilted front brace he can lean into, apparently at around 15 degrees. L. Dutch already posted a picture of a massage chair, so you know what I mean by this. Take out the head rest though, Albert doesn't need it - his cranial tilt is naturally high, so that if his body were vertical he'd be looking upwards. Also replace the tilted seat and leg rests, just focus on the chest support. Perhaps contour it a little to provide more support in the belly, if you're going for a more high-class look.

And for the final detail, the tail. Going from the image Albert's tail is supported primarily by the skeletal arrangements rather than constant muscle tension, so we don't need to worry too much about supporting it in the final model. If your lizardfolk have a droopy tail (poor guys) you might want to put a notch in the back of the seat itself to let the tail sit nicely. For Arthur and his buddies though, at most we'd put a small padded rear protrusion on the seat for comfort.

The end result is a flat horizontal seat slightly higher than the equivalent for humans, wide enough in the front to accommodate the slightly splayed seating style of the lizardfolk (that odd pelvic structure again) with a tilted front rest attached slightly forward of center of the seat via a narrow post, leaving plenty of room below the front rest for the thighs. Under the seat there is ample room for the hocks, either between the chair legs, as carved voids in a solid base or simply the result of a single supporting post attached to a wide base (like those god-awful spinning bar stools). Arm rests may be attached to the front rest as necessary, angled inwards for comfort or simply a horizontal shelf protruding from the front of the rest that will support the arms when folded across the chest, as though the one sitting were hugging the chair.

Mounting the chair would involve a forward squatting motion, spreading the knees around the front of the chair before bringing them back in to complete the seating process.

Of course you can add all sorts of features to the basic design for comfort or style. Moulded and padded seat, angled rests for the foot, fold-down front rests to make sitting easier, spikes and cuffs for restraint... uhm, that's for *special* use only, you should probably ignore those pages in the catalog. Albert is a respectable lizard after all.